# Scheduling tasks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a code in Java, something like this:

```
....
while (conditionX) {
  //fetch m
  ....
  t = new Thread(new SomeRunnable(m));
  t.start();
  Thread.sleep(500);
}
....

class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {
  String msisdn;
  public SomeRunnable (String m) {
    msisdn = m;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    do {
      //Statement block S uses msisdn, sets condition Y
      Thread.sleep(30000);    
    } while (conditionY);
  }
}
```

I am not comfortable with the number `Thread.sleep()`s I have used in the code. To avoid this I tried ScheduledExecutor etc, but couldn't really figure out a way to do what I want.
I need **half a second delay before a new thread is started**, and in the thread, there has to be a **30s delay before the statement block S is tried again**.

Please help me with a better way to code this using proper classes.
I have only provided an idea of how my code's work flow is, if I've to provide more info, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. Every half second you are creating a new thread that will do something every 30 seconds. Also, you are not starting your threads and in your Runnable implementation you are not overriding the `run()` method. Can you put up working code and/or specify your requirements better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Thread Sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413278/java-thread-sleep)

Comment: Please fix your syntax, this isn't valid Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and override [`run()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#run%28%29). Then you can schedule the task periodically with:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 500L, 30000L);
```

When you want to cancel your task, you can do that by calling [`cancel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring to configure your beans you can focus just on implementing your business logic and leverage Spring's hooks for managing the tasks, schedules, etc.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/scheduling.html